# cimport cpython, why are only some defined functions available?

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to create a python module that is converted to c using cython. The beginning of the example.pyx file includes:

```
#cython: language_level=3
import cpython
```

It seems as though some of https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/unicode.html is available to me, however, not all of the functions defined are e.g. cpython.PyUnicode_GET_SIZE can be used but not cpython.PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: Probably just that the wrapping was created before `PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH` was added to the C API and hasn't been systematically updated. Why not submit a patch for what you're missing?